# How to insert a column to a table in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, insert

I have read in some with Pandas and I want to add a column after the last column. After I did, the problem is that the values start from zero, and I want them to start from one.

I have 12800 rows and want the added column to start from 1 and go to 100 and the start over and go from 1 to 100. I want this pattern for all the rows. So basically I want this to cycle 128 times go from 1 to 100. Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('...csv')
df1=pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(12800, -1))
df1['10'] = df1.index
```

The included picture is not correct. I want the last column which is number 10 to start from one and have a pattern like I said above.

[image]

Comment: Do you want something like this? `df1['10'] = list(range(1, 101))*128`

Comment: @unmutto yes thanks and would you please tell me if i add another column and want the values from row zero to row 99 to be zero and row 100 to row 199 have value of one and this process goes on  until value of 127, how i can change the code?

Comment: You can use np.repeat(np.arange(0,128),100) for values from row zero to row 99 to be zero and row 100 to row 199 and so on

Comment: And np.tile(np.arange(1,101),128)) to print 1 to 100 128 times

Answer (score 0):

To repeat a pattern of `1..100` and assign to a column you can do:

```
df['1_to_100'] = np.tile(
    np.arange(1, 101), int(len(df) * 0.01) + 1)[:len(df)]
```

To add a pattern that is 100 per step you can do:

```
df['by_100'] = np.floor(df.index / 100)
```

**Test Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2002, 3))
df['1_to_100'] = np.tile(
    np.arange(1, 101), int(len(df) * 0.01) + 1 )[:len(df)]

df['by_100'] = np.floor(df.index / 100)

print(df.head())
print(df.tail())
```

**Results:**

```
          0         1         2  1_to_100  by_100
0  0.301862  0.824019  0.267810         1     0.0
1  0.568186  0.040328  0.799634         2     0.0
2  0.887218  0.407702  0.351990         3     0.0
3  0.871072  0.583761  0.498725         4     0.0
4  0.169657  0.026824  0.446667         5     0.0
             0         1         2  1_to_100  by_100
1997  0.370640  0.662019  0.541747        98    19.0
1998  0.545908  0.682259  0.970764        99    19.0
1999  0.416177  0.665771  0.926145       100    19.0
2000  0.207109  0.762653  0.813754         1    20.0
2001  0.711998  0.236817  0.025387         2    20.0
```